# Put inside Textarea button with Jsx (react)

Tags: reactjs, jsx

Okey small question from junior to pro about Jsx and react:

I have textarea and i wanna put inside button

```
    renderButton() {
    const { mod } = this.state
    return (
      <button className={classNames({
        [styles.button]: mod == 'default',
        [styles.fullScreenButton]: mod == 'fullscreen'
      })} onClick={this.fullScreen} >
      {this.renderIcon()}
      </button>
    )
  }

  render() {
    const { text, rows } = this.props
    const { mod } = this.state
    return (
      <div>
        <textarea rows={rows} value='text'
          className={classNames({
            [styles.textArea]: mod == 'default',
            [styles.fullScreen]: mod == 'fullscreen'
          })}>
        </textarea>
        {this.renderButton()}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

How i can do that?

Just

```
<textarea> <button> </button> </textarea>
```

not working 
Using position: absolute maybe yes, but have any another way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you have discovered, placing an HTML button as a child of a `<textarea>` will not work. This is not a limitation of React or JSX but of the `<textarea`> element. If you want the button to be placed inside the `<textarea>` visually you'll need to use CSS to reposition it. Something like this:

```css
div {
  position: relative;
}

textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

button {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 15px;
  right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <textarea>
  </textarea>
  <button>Submit</button>
</div>
```