# Dealing with click events on stacked elements

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, dom-events

hi guys im having troubles, lets say i have this on my app

```
 - wrapper-div
     - child-div#1
     - child-div#2
         - granchild-div#1
```

`child-div#1` have a `zIndex: 1`  and `child-div#2` is an `position:absolute` div thats directly behind `child-div#1` same height and width,

my problem is i need to capture click events on `granchild-div#1` but it is behind `child-div#1` and `child-div#1` have an textarea child thats in front

What ive tried:
I tried doing `pointer-events: none` to `child-div#1` but it removes the pointer events.. and `child-div#1` needs the pointer events too

here's a sample code

app.js

```
const app = () => {
  const [value,setValue] = useState("test [string]")

  return (
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div>
        <input class="input" value={value} onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)} type="text" />
      </div>
      <div class="renderer">
        {value.map((word,i) => <span key={i}>{word}</span>)}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

app.css

```
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.text-area {
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
  resize: none;
}

.render {
  width: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
}
```

and a [codesandbox example here](https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-solomon-3rxnob?file=/src/App.js:208-217)

Comment: Can you pop some code up so we can have a look?

Comment: @Adam edited it and added codesandbox link to a sample

Comment: Please read about how you should provide a [mcve]. The code must be included **in the question itself**, preferably in a code snippet.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44351435. I'm not sure you will be able to make this button work inside the text area. You may have to rearrange the hierarchy and position it through CSS.

Comment: @ChrisDueck Not really, im not looking on placing the button inside the text area,  its gonna behind, the text area will be invisible..

Comment: @jasjamjos As far as I know this isn't possible. You would have to have the textarea placed next to the button rather than behind/on top so that both can receive the clicks correctly. If you just want to be able to write into a button, you could make your own component with a displayed value and onClick event. If I'm misunderstanding, you'll need to provide more detail.